# Using Selenium in Python, webscraping using find elements by xpath, .text

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, formatting, string-formatting

I'm trying to automate a task that I have to do every week using Python and Selenium.

I go to a website and if there is any new files I download them, rename them using the date they came in and who they went to, and then place them in a folder on the shared network server.

The website provides the date in which the file comes in through a clickable link.

Using find elements by xpath, and what I assume are parameters, starts with and contains, I've been able to search through all the links with the date and time.

```
receivedTime = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[starts-with(@id, 
"anchor") and contains(@id, "_0")]')
for time in receivedTime:
 print(time.text)
```

The output looks like this for example, "11/2/2018, 8:00:50 AM".

I would like to format that text to say "2018-11-02", how would I go about doing that?

It's my understanding that the variable **time** is just an object of the Current Xpath and .text is just a property of that object. Is my understanding correct?

Thank you.

ANSWER:

```
receivedTime = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[starts-with(@id, 
"anchor") and contains(@id, "_0")]')
for time in receivedTime:
 date = str(time.text).split(',')
 dateTime = datetime.strptime(date[0], '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d-')
 print(dateTime)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the package [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) (`import datetime`) 
The **time** variable is a string so you have to convert it into **datetime** and change the format like this :

```
date = str(time.text).split(',')
datetime.datetime.strptime(date[0], '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: I'm already using the package datetime to compare dates, so this is nice.

Comment: If I understand this correctly.

You set the date as a variable to equal the string of time.text then used the command split to split the string before and after the ,

From there, you use the datetime package and the string to datetime function to convert the string to a datetime. 

(Best guess) - date[0] is setting the variable date to only what is in front of the comma and the 0 removes what is after it. Also formatting the datetime in the process

Then using strftime to convert datetime back to string in the wanted format.

Is that correct?

Comment: receivedTime = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[starts-with(@id, "anchor") and contains(@id, "_0")]')
for time in receivedTime:
    date = str(time.text).split(',')
    dateTime = datetime.strptime(date[0], '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d-')
    print(dateTime)

Comment: Yes that's correct, I used split() to select just `11/2/2018` because this is what need to be formatted.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I found my answer using the code and logic you provided with some alterations. You can find the code after the edit I made to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a regular expression to extract the numbers and reformat the date:

```
import re
text = "11/2/2018, 8:00:50 AM"
date_tuple = re.match("(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)", text).groups()
file_name = "%d-%02d-%02d" % (int(date_tuple[2]), int(date_tuple[0]), int(date_tuple[1]))
```

Result: "2018-11-02"

Comment: Never have used the package re before.

Would have to put text as whatever the xpath currently is as it changes.

Not sure what the d+ are in date_tuple, best guess is a placeholder.

Not sure what the %02 in file_name stand for.

Everything else I understand on certain level.